# Async/await Not working with AWS S3 Node.js SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've created a very short/simple example of a problem I'm having with `Promise`s in a script utilizing the `aws-sdk` package for Node.js.

In short, the script is *not* waiting at the `await` keyword. It loops through the loop without waiting for the `async` function to successfully complete before moving on.

Code example:

---

`main.js`

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
import constants from '@/constants'

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: constants.awsAccessKey,
  secretAccessKey: constants.awsSecretAccessKey,
  region: constants.awsRegion
})

export const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'})
```

*click some button and trigger `testS3()` method...*

---

`testActions.js`

```
import { s3 } from '@/main.js'

export async function testS3 () {
  const testParams = {
    Bucket: AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `test_file.txt`,
    Body: 'Testing stuff'
  }

  async function testFunction(layer) {
    console.log('in prepare design 1')
    const result = await s3.putObject(testParams).promise()
    console.log(`the results: ${result}`)
  }

  [1,2,3].forEach(async (x) => {
    const result = await testFunction()
  })
}
```

---

Output from the debugger:

[image]

---

I was expecting the messages to be *interleaved*, which is what makes sense if you follow the flow of the logic.

It should be `in prepare design 1`, and **then** display `the results...`, then go through and do that 2 more times.

The output displaying `in prepare design 1` three times right off the bat shows me that the loop is not waiting for the function before continuing.

---

Have I setup `async`/`await` wrong in some way? I've tried multiple different iterations and can't seem to get this working how I'm expecting it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The displayed behavior is correct, because `forEach`'s handler is also an `async` function:

```
  async (x) => {
    const result = await testFunction()
  }
```

So the `forEach` loop will run 3 async functions immediately. Each of those function will `await` for the rest of the promise chain asynchronously.

If you want a synchronous execution, use a normal for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  const result = await testFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This an addition to AVAVT's answer (as I can't comment on it), you can also do so as such so you don't have to manually enter in the number of iterations and intending on using the iterating value.

```
import { s3 } from '@/main.js'

export async function testS3 () {
  const testParams = {
    Bucket: AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `test_file.txt`,
    Body: 'Testing stuff'
  }

  async function testFunction(layer) {
    console.log('in prepare design 1')
    const result = await s3.putObject(testParams).promise()
    console.log(`the results: ${result}`)
  }

  for (const iterator of [1,2,3]) {
      const result = await testFunction();
  }

}
```

Comment: promise() at last is the solution. Thank you so much